# How to stop NetLogo simulation

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a simulation of Covid19 spread for months: May and June
The code I am using to create turtles and start simulation is showed below:

```
to gh-month    
if month="May"//month is a chooser in interface tabe
[
clear-all

create-turtles 3000
[
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
set shape forma
set color blue

]
set no_infected 106
ask n-of 1 turtles  with [color = blue]
[
set infectedTurtle? True
set color red
]
set percentage(no_infected / 3000)* 100
]
if month="June"
[
  clear-all
  create-turtles 3000
  [
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set shape forma
  set color blue
  ]

  set no_infected 2030
  ask n-of 1 turtles  with [color = blue]
  [
   set infectedTurtle? True
   set color red
  ]
   set percentage(no_infected / 3000)* 100
  ]
 end
```

And setup and go commands are below

```
    to setup
      gh-month
    end
    to go
      reset-ticks                               ;; netlogo time
      ask turtles [
      forward 0.005                      ;; moving turtles command and speed
      ]
     ask turtles with [color = red] [
     ask other turtles-here [
    if random 100 < percentage[set color red]
    ]
  ]
    set %infected (count turtles with [color = red] / count turtles) * 100
    if %infected= percentage[stop]//percentage is declared above also is a monitor in interface tab
 end
```

My question after simulation start, why for the month' May' is stopped ate based on given condition(if %infected= percentage[stop]), and for June no, it goes up to 100% and don't stop at given condtion.
Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

You have a basic misunderstanding of how time operates in NetLogo so there are several problems. You have also written way too much code at once. For example, just create the turtles and get that working before having them move, and get that working before trying to have different months.

NetLogo works with a counter or clock. Each `tick` increments the counter. The `reset-ticks` is part of the initialisation because it sets the counter to 0 and makes it available. The command `tick` advances the clock, and is usually the last command in the procedure that contains all the things that happen in a day (or hour or whatever a tick represents). The go procedure therefore needs the command `tick`, not the command `reset-ticks`.